Constructive mathematics with different computational models
I am interested in understanding how the capabilities of constructive mathematics evolve when different computational models are considered. Specifically, if constructive mathematics traditionally aligns with the computational power of Turing machines, what happens if we extend our computational model to include:

Infinite Time Turing Machines (ITTMs)
Universal Hypercomputer - defined in https://arxiv.org/abs/1806.08747

Specifically, if we assume the existence of a universal hypercomputer, would this make the entire set-theoretic universe of classical mathematics constructible within a constructive framework?

There has been some work on realizability toposes relative to these kinds of notions. (See for instance Bauer's blog post on realizability toposes relative to infinite-time Turing machines.) The general idea is to use the notion of computation to define a partial combinatory algebra (PCA) and then use a certain general definition of 'realizability topos relative to a PCA.'

I'm unfortunately not familiar with the universal hypercomputer. For ITTMs, the realizability topos is indeed quite interesting. LEM fails, but Markov's principle and indeed LPO (for the natural numbers) hold. DC holds and hence Cauchy and Dedekind reals agree. There is an injection from $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ and from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{N}$ (however there is no surjection $\mathbb{N} \twoheadrightarrow \mathbb{R}$). We also used this setting as a countermodel for differentiating between certain Noetherian conditions.

So it would seem that as we have more powerful notion of computation we get more of the classical set theory into our constructive framework (relative to the computational construction) and if we take a limit of this - which should be the Universal Hypercomputer, we would get the whole classical set theory
